# How to get a list of Pull Requests filtered by numbers through GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

I can't find the way hot to get information about several PRs inside one repo/branch filtered by their numbers from GitHub API. I'm trying to analyze git history and find pull requests titles merged in a branch during a period of time.

Here I see only filter by `state`.
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to find the merged PRs in a repo/branch during a period of time, it is possible using the GitHub Search Issues API.

For example:  if you want to find all PRs in repo `km-poonacha/testissues`, created between `2017-06-01..2017-06-16` and that are `merged`you can make the following request - `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:km-poonacha/testissues+type:pr+created:2017-06-01..2017-06-16+is:merged`.

Ref. [Search Issues and Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/)

Comment: Thank you, @Poonacha, but is it possible to get the same not between dates, but between commit hashes? Or, even better to get just by numbers, because I already did some history analysis before in my code and I have a bulk of PRs numbers for which I want to load details.

Comment: Oh sure, with PR numbers it is even better. I.e. `https://api.github.com/repos/REPONAME/pulls/PR#`. For example for PR#20 for repo `km-poonacha/testissues` : `https://api.github.com/repos/km-Poonacha/testissues/pulls/20`

Comment: But what if I have 30 PRs – do I need to make 30 calls? That is exactly what I want to avoid. :) So, I'm trying to get a bulk of PRs with one API query.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I do not know the answer for this case.